# Error #1064: phpMyAdmin import showing html errors in a MYSQL database - why html?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to import a database into phpMyAdmin (I'm using MAMP) and I'm getting the Static Analysis Error report below. I exported the db using phpMyAdmin from a Bluehost server. I have also tried MYSQL40 format, but the same error occurs.

[image]

I don't understand why there is is html showing here - any clarification would be very helpful.

I've trawled the internet for solutions, however, all the fixes are there for fixing issues around MYSQL queries, not MYSQL queries embedded in html, so any pointers on how to fix this issue, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused by the database entries created by the a minification plugin in Wordpress. Deleting the plugin and the associated tables in the database removes the problem.